# Point and click game where there were a handful of ghosts you had to help “release”

Tags: story-identification, video-games, ghost

So when I was younger, around 8 years ago, I remember playing this point and click hidden object horror Big Fish game, but basically there were a handful of ghosts you had to help "release" (?) and the whole fashion of the game was from the 1950s (think *Grease*) and I remember particularly during the game when you took too long or were idling, the ghosts in the room you were looking in would pop up on the screen.

The characters in the game were cartoonish, yet realistic, and all the colors were bright from what I can remember. You aren't a ghost yourself if I recall correctly, and each ghost had a room of their own coordinating to their style, i.e. the greaser had a garage, the opera singer/actor had a dressing room, etc.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if those prompts give you any additional material to add to the question.

Comment: There are an infinity of hidden object games out there.  I'll mention the only one I've played because it's vaguely close (*Three Cards to Midnight*), but it wasn't really about ghosts, it was about memories.

Comment: Was that something which got a "physical" release (CD etc), or did you play it online? If the former, where did you buy it, what did the jacket look like? If the latter, do you remember what kind of sites you used to go to?

Comment: Brings to mind Phantasmagoria, but that was mid 90's (And the only game I ever demanded a refund for).

Comment: There is [The Lost Crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Crown:_A_Ghost-Hunting_Adventure) - Says the depictions were taken from Cornwall photography, and you exorcise several ghosts during the hunt.

Comment: @Solei: I think I may have found your game. Can you verify?

Answer (score 5):

With the additional information, I'm guessing this might be Big Fish's *Mishap: an Accidental Haunting* (unfortunately, Big Fish doesn't seem to sell the game on their site anymore, although you can play it as a demo from [here](https://www.bigfishgames.com/download-games/7308/mishap-an-accidental-haunting/download_pnp.html?afcode=af29bc6b9822&channel=affiliates&identifier=af29bc6b9822) and [buy it on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003FSSINA)).

> The Burtons have just moved into a beautiful new home, which just happens to be haunted. Now it's up to you to help them deal with some particularly unfortunate ghosts as you search for Hidden Object through beautifully illustrated rooms. Help the Burtons survive the paranormal and take back their home in Mishap: An Accidental Haunting.

It sports a number of ghosts in various rooms. There's a greaser-looking ghost and an actress ghost.

[image: Bedroom Ghost] [image: Ballroom ghost]

[This walkthrough](https://www.bigfishgames.com/blog/walkthrough/mishap-an-accidental-haunting-walkthrough/) provides images of most of the scenes, albeit, of course, also spoilers. Alternately, the opening cinematic:

It looks like it was followed up by *Mishap 2: an Intentional Haunting*, which has [a walkthrough entry](https://www.bigfishgames.com/blog/walkthrough/mishap-2-an-intentional-haunting-walkthrough/), and [a page on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004JN12X8).

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.